# Determining the Unit of Spatial Resolution of a raster image in Python

Tags: python, raster, gdal, rasterio

I have some raster images, and I would like to determine the GSD using Python.

I know that I can use `rasterio.transform()`  or `gdal.GetGeoTransform()`  to extract the spatial resolution of the image.

How do I determine the units of the spatial resolution.

Comment: I don't think I've seen this called GSD before, and for anyone else it stands for "Ground Sampling Distance". (My default for GSD is German Shepherd Dog)

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear enough I updated the question. I was hoping there would be a way to use the spatial resolution to determine the GSD.

Comment: Is the spatial resolution not equivalent to the GSD?

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/115035/8104

Comment: Thanks a lot, in this case I will rephrase the question so that others can benefit.

Comment: @Aaron, If you can, re-upload your answer, so that I can accept it as the accepted answer then that would be great!

Comment: Will do. Thanks for clarifying your original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`linear_units`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.crs.html#rasterio.crs.CRS.linear_units) property in the [`crs`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.crs.html#rasterio.crs.CRS) class. For example:

```
import rasterio

raster = rasterio.open('/path/to/your/raster.tif' )

print(raster.crs.linear_units)
```

Comment: What if this just sayis `'unknown'` ? :( Showing this rater in QGis, for example, knows where to put each pixel, so surely it can calculate GSD, no?

Comment: Is there an equivalent for GDAL?

Comment: @dazonic This may be helpful: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/368008/8104

Comment: @Aaron that only get the x and y res in numbers, I’m looking for a way to get units, ie degrees or metres